# My SQL query runs well in SQL dev and returns Two records but it returns blank value when I use same query in "Add Command" in Crystal report

Tags: crystal-reports, business-objects

I have a SQL query in SQL Developer (Oracle Database), which runs well and returns 4 columns and 2 records but if I use the same query in Add Command in Crystal Report it returns blank values.

- `p.Name` (In DB in schema1, Data type VARCHAR2(100 Char), Eg: "SAP Consulting LLC")
- `TN.TNA` In DB in schema1, Data type VARCHAR2(25 Char),  Eg: "123-456788")
- `P.SUB` (In DB in schema1, Data type VARCHAR2(25 Char),  Eg: "0")
- `P.M_NO` (In DB in schema1, Data type VARCHAR2(25 Char),  Eg: "123456")

Code:

```
    with ABC as (
    select pnc.p_id from schema1.pp_pnc pnc, schema1.pp_n pn
    where PNC.N_ID = PN.id
    and PN.DS = 'ABC'
    and PNC.END_DATE like '01-JAN-20'),
    EFG as (select pnc.p_id from schema1.pp_pnc pnc, schema1.pp_n pn
    where PNC.N_ID = PN.id
    and PN.DS = 'EFG'
    and PNC.END_DATE like '01-JAN-00')
          
    select distinct P.name, TN.TNA, P.SUB , P.M_NO
    from schema.PETA P
    inner join SCHEMA1.ALPHA PTPC on P.id = PTPC.P_ID
    inner join schema1.BETA TN on PTPC.TN_ID = TN.id
    inner join ABC on P.id=ABC.P_ID
    inner join EFG on P.id=EFG.P_ID
    where PTPC.END_DATE > sysdate
    and TN.TNA not in ('123-456788', '456-457896')
```

Comment: Check if you are using the correct database. 

Can you debug that code to see if the query returns values ? Maybe the tenant is missing ?

Comment: @TheOne__- Database is correct and the query runs good and returns the values(2 records each for Name, TNA, SUB and M_no (returns null)).

Comment: Could be the way you are handling your dates. This may work in SQL Developer due to NLS settings but may not work in sql.
Replace PNC.END_DATE like '01-JAN-20' with: 
TO_CHAR(PNC.END_DATE,'DD-MON-YY') = '01-JAN-20'
Same for 01-JAN-00...